# Scraping noise when braking

Tags: brakes, subaru, forester, braking

I own a Subaru Forester 2015, and as I was driving down the road the other day, I had the misfortune of hitting a deer. It wasn't a terrible hit, but left a nasty crack on my front left bumper. Ever since then my front left brake makes a weird scraping-like noise when ever I hit the brakes.

The brakes on the car are brand new, maybe about a month or 2 old. There hasn't been any issues in driving besides that noise.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but I'm not really sure what the question is. You know where the noise is coming from. You will need to pull off the wheel and look for anything rubbing/scraping the rotor, or take it to a mechanic if you are not comfortable doing this. If it's a 2015 I would guess that you have collision insurance, so this (along with the damage to your bumper) should be covered.

Comment: No rudeness taken. I'm asking people to help identify what could be wrong so I'm not panicking until I have the chance to take it to a mechanic. Maybe I need to panic, but I don't know, I'm fairly clueless when it comes to cars. Just to be clear, sure its pretty easy to assume that something's scraping, but what? All I did was hit a deer at about 25 mph, what about that could cause a scraping noise in my brakes?

Comment: If I had the knowledge to check it my self or the time to bring it to a mechanic, I wouldn't be asking a public forum.

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if the plastic on the inside of the wheel well popped loose. It may be rubbing the tire when you brake (or maybe turn).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check the tyres for any rubbing marks around the outer side tread area. Its possible that when braking and the front of the vehicle dips down a little the bodywork is rubbing on the tyre.

If the noise is from the brakes themselves they'll need checking over, just to make sure that any debris or damage from the accident hasn't found its way between the moving parts or possibly bent a disks backplate etc.